# Adding more difficult Matrices

Tags: matrices, arithmetic

I've already asked a question similar to this but this one is more difficult and plus want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly.

I've got this equation below:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & -1 \\
    4 & -5 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
+ 2*
    \begin{bmatrix}
    7 & -5 & 1 \\
    1 & -4 & -3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I believe it is solved like so:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & -1 \\
    4 & -5 & 2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
+
    \begin{bmatrix}
    14 & -10 & 2 \\
    2 & -8 & -6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    16 & -10 & 1 \\
    6 & -13 & -4 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Am I doing the addition right? Add both row 1's together then both row 2's together. For example, it would look something like this, when adding:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    2+14 & 0-10 & -1 + 2 \\
    4+2 & -5-8 & 2+-6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

EDIT: caught an addition error I made with the 2 + 14 for my final answer. Originally I had 28 down because I was multiplying but I think what I want is 16.

Comment: Everything there is correct.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought but i'm still new to this and my teacher doesn't explain it too well.

Comment: Would it help if I said that matrices are vectors and follow the identical rules for addition and scalar multiplication?  If not, don't worry, I don't know how the subject has been introduced to you.

Comment: Addition and scalar multiplication are done coefficientwise.

Comment: Perhaps use a word other than complex in your title since complex numbers mean something else...

Comment: Doug, it does make sense. I've done these a couple of times and I think I'm slowly catching on.

Comment: @DougM Could you please post your comment as an answer so this question can be removed from the "unanswered" queue?

Answer (score 2):

Robert Howard, per your request:

Everything there is correct.

Matrices are vectors and follow the identical rules for addition and scalar multiplication.